# How do I fix the error in my Dart launch.json file?

Tags: json, dart, visual-studio-code

I was learning some tutorials on Dart input but it seems it can only run in a terminal. Unfortunately, I keep getting this error
**.vscode/launch.json:1:1: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '{'.
{
^**
And this is the code in my launch.json file:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Dart & Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": ".vscode/launch.json",
            "console": "externalTerminal"   
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the output of code --list - extensions:

```
adelphes.android-dev-ext
Dart-Code.dart-code
Dart-Code.flutter
eamodio.gitlens
esbenp.prettier-vscode
formulahendry.code-runner
jeff-hykin.better-cpp-syntax
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers
ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
ms-vscode.cmake-tools
ms-vscode.cpptools
ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack
ms-vscode.cpptools-themes
PKief.material-icon-theme
streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker
timkmecl.codegpt3
twxs.cmake
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
```

Comment: I don't get that error :/ What version of VS Code do you have installed? What's the output of `code --list-extensions`?

Comment: @user - My version of vscode is 1.78.0

Answer (score 0):

The `program` field is supposed to be a Dart script, but you have set it to the launch.json itself:

```
"program": ".vscode/launch.json",
```

This should be something like `"lib/main.dart"` or `"bin/main.dart"`.

You can also just delete the `"program"` line entirely if you want the Dart extension to infer it from your open files/workspace (if the open file is inside `bin/`, `tool/` or `test/` it will run it, otherwise it will look for some common files like `bin/main.dart`).